# Python module logging with eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, logging, module, package

I am trying to get logging going across a couple of different modules using     `logging.config.fileConfig()` My directory looks something like this:

```
> Package
   > Source
       __init__.py
       SomeSource.py
   > Test
       __init__.py
       SomeTests.py
   __init__.py
```

Inside in `Package.__init__.py` I have the following:

```
directory = 'C:/User/Me/workspace/Package/'
logFile = 'logger.conf'
logging.config.fileConfig(directory+logFile)
log = logging.getLogger('Package')
log.info('Logging initialized.')

import Test
```

Inside in `Package.Test.__init__.py` I have

```
log = logging.getLogger('Package.Test')
log.info('Test module started')
```

So the expected output for this is something like:

```
Logging initialized.
Test Module started.
```

I can get this to run and log correctly while using eclipse using Ctrl+F11. However, calling it from the interpreter results in nothing at all:

```
>>> import Package
```

The log file remains empty. Any ideas?

Comment: It might help if you post your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

By default the verbosity of logging in an interactive interpreter session will be WARNING, so your INFO messages won't show (Eclipse or a plugin may set the verbosity differently).

Change your .info calls to .warning calls - you should see some output (depending on how your configuration is set up in the conf file).

Alternatively, in your interactive session, do

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

before

```
import Package
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I have already set the logging to `DEBUG` in the config file that `fileConfig()` is reading from. Setting the logging level to `WARNING` or `CRITICAL` for my log messages does not work. Using `setLevel()` yields the same results. This is quite confusing as I would have imagined Eclipse uses the same mechanism to execute Python code.